# convert to numeric : simplify 2 calls of gsub to one

Tags: regex, r

I would like to convert a vector of alphanumeric to numeric vector.  Right now , I am using regex but with 2 calls to `gsub`:

```
## wrapping this in function 
to_numeric <-
  function(x)    gsub(',','.',gsub("[^(\\d|,)]","",x,perl=TRUE))
## call it 
to_numeric(c('a12,12','Atr 145 ',' 14 5,1 4A'))
## [1] "12.12"  "145"    "145.14"
```

How can I simplify this to one call, using unique regex or any other method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use two functions..

Comment: `[^(\\d|,)]` this looks fishy, though. Do you want to exclude `\d` and `,` only? Or do you want to exclude `()|` also?

Comment: you don't _need_ to use two functions, it's just not pretty or efficient, unless you can count on digits being contiguous...

Comment: @agstudy: I guess you can use `mgsub` from *qdap*, something like this: `library(qdap) //
find <- c(",","[^\\d,]") //
replace <- c(".","") //
to_numeric <- //
  function(x)    mgsub(find, replace, x, fixed = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use cascading calls to make the different replacements if using base R.

However, you can utilize the [**gsubfn**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) package, simplifying it using a replacement list.

```
library(gsubfn)

x <- c('a12,12', 'Atr 145 ', ' 14 5,1 4A')

gsubfn('\\D+', list(',' = '.', ''), x)
# [1] "12.12"  "145"    "145.14"
```